# What is the difference between Specific and General Exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

I would like to know the difference between Specific and General Exception in C#. If anyone answer me with an example would be a great helpful.

Comment: A specific one provides more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Difference : Please refer example for clear understanding

**Example :**

```
    class Program
   {
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            int[] array = new int[100];
            array[0] = 1;
            array[10] = 2;
            array[200] = 3; // this line will through *IndexOutOfRangeException* Exception

            object o = null;
            o.ToString(); // this line will through *NullReferenceException* Exception
        }
        /* the below catch block(IndexOutOfRangeException class) will only catch *IndexOutOfRangeException* and not *NullReferenceException*
          hence you can say it as Specific Exception as it is catching only a particular exception.
        */
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Index"); // Or any of you Custom error message etc.
        }
        /* the below catch block(Exception class) will catch all the type of exception and hence you can call it as Generic Exception.
        */
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opps Something Went Wrong..."); // Or any of you Custom error message etc.
        }

    }
}
```

**Specific Exception :** As you see in the example above IndexOutOfRange is handling only one type of exception hence you can say it as specific exception.

**Generic Exception :**  These Exception classes can handle any kind of exception. So can call it as generalized exception.

You can get more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tca6706%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For Hierarchy of Exceptions you can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5tckx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. It's well explained.